# How to write CmakeLists.txt to include xgboost in c

Tags: c++, cmake, xgboost

I am new in Mac OS system. Recently, I was doing a project that requires to use xgboost to predict in c language. My question is how to write the CmakeLists.txt file correctly.

I did it step by step according to a guide document. Actually, I got the cpp run correctly using the following command:

```
g++ main.c -Ixgboost/include -Ixgboost/rabit/include xgboost/lib/libxgboost.a xgboost/rabit/lib/librabit_empty.a xgboost/dmlc-core/libdmlc.a
```

However, When I turn to the CmakeLists.txt, something wrong happens. Here is the error code:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libxgboost.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/doubleding/Documents/Develop_SCIP/tryLoadXgboost/cmake-build-debug/tryLoadXgboost
Reason: image not found
```

Here is the code for CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(tryLoadXgboost C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xgboost/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xgboost/rabit/include)


link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xgboost/lib)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xgboost/rabit/lib)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xgboost/dmlc-core) #库文件目录

add_executable(tryLoadXgboost main.c)

target_link_libraries(tryLoadXgboost libxgboost.a)
target_link_libraries(tryLoadXgboost librabit_empty.a )
target_link_libraries(tryLoadXgboost libdmlc.a)
```

I know there is some topic about "dyld: Library not loaded:". But I don't know how to do it in this specific task. In addition, I don't know if it is my fault in writing the cmakelists (because using g++ there is no error).  I would appreciate very much if someone could tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find all the boost libraries;

```
$ otool -L exefile
exefile:
        @executable_path/libboost_something.dylib (compatibility version 0.7.0, current version 0.7.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 65.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

for each `libboost_something.dylib` you will need to do

```
$ install_name_tool -change @executable_path/libboost_something.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_something.dylib exefile
```

if that doesnt work, you can use a workaround of using the static version of Boost instead of the dynamic one.

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

Comment: but I am using xgboost rather than boost. Actually, I tried the install_name_tool command. It says: Did find:
 xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
Abort trap: 6